# chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’:

Tags: linux, bash, scp, qemu

I am trying to modify a kernel image before using it for qemu. I am trying to add a compiled binary to the image. I am using 64 bit Linux 14.02. What I am doing is,

```
linaro-media-create --image_file vexpress.img --dev vexpress --binary linaro-natty.tar.gz --hwpack hwpack_linaro.tar.gz
sudo mount -o loop,offset=$((106496*512)) -t auto vexpress.img /mnt
cd /mnt 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo chroot . 
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

I need to get past this error in order to scp files into the image. Kindly help.

Comment: The error says there is no `/mnt/bin/bash`. Maybe you are chrooting to the wrong directory (e.g. `/mnt` instead of `/mnt/something`). Post the output of `ls /mnt`.

Comment: @user49740 output is bin   etc         lib         media  proc  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
boot  home        lost+found  mnt    root  srv      usr
dev   initrd.img  md5sum.txt  opt    sbin  sys      var

Comment: Looks decent. Post the output of `ls /mnt/bin/*sh`. Maybe you don't have bash but you do have another shell.

Comment: @user49740 out put is, /mnt/bin/bash  /mnt/bin/dash  /mnt/bin/rbash  /mnt/bin/sh

Comment: So bash exists. Maybe your chroot is i386 (32-bit)? Post the output of `file /mnt/bin/bash`.

Comment: @user49740 ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16 and x86-64.

Comment: That's the problem. I'll write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a 32-bit program (`/mnt/bin/bash`) on a 64-bit system.

To do this you should enable multiarch and install the libraries you need (such as libc6).

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386
```

Comment: thanks for the help so far. i have installed libc but the error persists. Same error.

Comment: Run `ldd /mnt/bin/bash`. You should install all libraries listed there. An easier way to do this is to `apt-get install bash:i386`.

Comment: If the libraries are installed into the original `/` directory, won't they become inaccessible after the `chroot`? You would need to run the 32-bit `bash` before the `chroot`. An alternative approach is to boot a 32-bit Live CD and do the modifications from there.

Comment: That is right. I'm still wondering why the 32-bit `bash` won't run as long as the loader is installed (the chroot presumably contains the needed libraries). Running `/mnt/bin/bash` and trying to `chroot` from there sounds like a very good idea.

Comment: @AFH i have tried this on 32 bit linux too. facing same error. followed all steps mentioned in this post.

Comment: @user49740 sorry, i didnt get what you are trying to suggest here..

Comment: @user49740 /mnt/bin/bash is saying /lib/ld-linux.so.3: No such file or directory

Comment: Uh. I just reread the `file` output in the comment for your post. Your chroot is for ARM, not x86(-64). In other words, you either need an ARM cpu (e.g. a Raspberry Pi) or QEMU. With QEMU, the command is something like `qemu-system-arm -hda /path/to/vexpress.img`.

Comment: i think I am doing this with qemu, as posted here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oh3NK12fnbg. I am successfully doing it for the another mounted image but getting problem with vexpress.img